# how to specify DNS IP in wicd?

Tags: resolv.conf, wicd

I am trying to use a different DNS server other than my router.

I've tried editing /etc/resolv.conf, but my changes always get overwritten.

Here's my networks' config:

[image: Here is my network's config]

Yet, this is what my /etc/resolv.conf file looks like:

```
# Generated by resolvconf
search myhome.westell.com
nameserver 192.168.1.1
```

Comment: I would file a bug report with that. The ncurses interface should set your DNS.

Answer (score 2):

I'm having the same problem, i believe the culprit is dhclient, which gets
run automatically by wicd. whenever the dhcp lease expires, dhclient overwrites 
/etc/resolv.conf with what it gets from the the dhcp server.

to verify that this is indded your problem, do "ps aux | grep dhclient", you should
an entry pop up, referencing a configuration file for dhclient (on my machine it's
at /var/lib/wicd/dhclient.conf).

to fix this, you need to edit  /etc/wicd/dhclient.conf.template 
(NOT /etc/wicd/dhclient.conf.template.default)

and add a line like the following:

supersede 208.67.222.220 208.67.222.20;

then restart the wicd service with

> sudo service wicd restart

this will instruct dhclient to set resolv.conf to the manually specified servers,
rather then to what your dhcp server (i'm guessing the home router at 192.168.1.1?)
is sending you.

wicd should really handle this for you, but this will solve your problem for now.
seems to solve the issue for me.

Comment: Hey there.. so I tried this and it seemed to work, but I started getting "dns lookup failed"  and I realized /etc/resolv.conf is being overwritten, with 192.168.1.1 :(

Answer (score 1):

Start wicd by searching for 'wicd' in the dash.
Once wicd has been started, select your network and click on "Properties"
[image]

In the properties dialog box, check 'Use Static DNS'
[image]

Enter your preferred DNS Servers in the "DNS Server 1, 2 and 3" boxes. 
The DNS domain and the search domain can be left empty. For example for OpenDNS , I just enter the 2 DNS servers.