# How to use static IP with Wicd wireless?

Tags: wireless, networking, wicd

After constant problems with network manager, I switched to Wicd which works better.

I found some related questions (like this one: [how to specify DNS IP in wicd?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/87468/how-to-specify-dns-ip-in-wicd) - but it is for wired, not wireless).

Wicd does not seem to have a place to set static IP forr wireless.

How to use static IP with Wicd wireless?

Ubuntu 11.04.
Wicd 1.7.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to set up a static wireless IP in Wicd, but it must be done for each network individually.

If you already know how to find your IP address, subnet mask, and gateway, open up the Wicd GUI (if you don't have it, install [wicd-gtk](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/wicd-gtk)), go to your selected wireless network, and open the Preferences menu (if you don't know how to find these items I'll explain later).

Check the "Use static IPs" and enter your information here. You can also manually specify your DNS domain and servers.

About network info: You can find your IP and subnet mask with

```
ifconfig
```

and your gateway with

```
route -n
```

Comment: It worked. By the way, this was very difficult (if not impossible) using Network Manager...

Comment: Yeah, network-manager has some serious issues in Precise

Comment: I was using it with 11.04.